# Unix-Splitting 1 column into two columns

Tags: shell, unix

I have dataset as follows:

```
item  gram
tomato 500
orange 1500
bread  2000
```

Now they seem to be separated as shown (for example, tomato 500, not tomato500), but they are all in one column when I make a csv file. I want items go into one column and gram goes into another column to be:

```
item       gram
tomato     500
orange     1500
bread      2000
```

Comment: Which software are you using or what program should view the resultung csv? I think you only need to specify the correct field delimiter (it seems space or tab).

Comment: I need to make table with two columns in Excel, so I want to make a csv file.

Comment: Excel offers detailed control how to "interpret" text data. There is an icon in the ribbon called something like import text data.  
You copy/paste your content from the clipboard into excel, it is interpreted by whatever settings are currently active and the whole text is still selected.  
Now you find and click that button to change the settings:  
1. not fixed but delimited by a charachter  
2. choose space or tab in the next step.  
Excel applies the changed settings to the selected text, thus splitting it into two columns (check it out, it is easier to use than to describe :) ).

Comment: Another option it to find out what excel uses as list field delimiter and use that character when creating the file. This setting can be found in the regional settings of windows or excel (I am not sure where it is).

Comment: I did it! Thanks. But, isn't there any command to automatically does it without doing such changes in Excel?

Comment: Use the field delimiter that excel is expecting when creating the files.

Answer (score 1):

To change runs of spaces to a tab,

```
tr -s ' ' $'\t' <old.txt >new.tsv
```

where `old.txt` is your input file and `new.tsv` contains the new output from `tr`.

Your example shows multiple spaces between some values. If you always have exactly one space between values, or want to change *n* spaces to *n* tabs, take out the `-s` (though of course in the former case, it doesn't really matter).

`$'\t'` is a (Bash-only) quoting mechanism which allows you to pass a literal tab as an argument. `tr` does not have an entirely portable syntax for this, though you could probably use `'\t'` on most modern systems as well.

The second argument to `tr` specifies what character to use as the new separator. I chose tab as separator because that's what Excel expected for what it (somewhat confusedly) calls "Unix" files last time I looked. To use commas (for proper CSV) or semicolon (which is apparently preferred over comma in some locales, because they use comma as the decimal separator in numbers; even though Excel still calls the format CSV) use `','` or `';'` as the second argument, respectively.

(The single quotes are important to prevent the shell from performing any interpretation. For example, the semicolon character is a command separator in the shell, so you would get a rather bewildering error message if you forget to quote it.)

`tr` uncoditionally replaces all instances of the characters you specify. If you want more detailed control (conditional or context-dependent replacement) you need a more complex tool, like `sed`.

The details of the CSV format are actually rather complex, and there are several dialects, even between different versions of Excel, so you might need to experiment a bit if your real data is more complex than your example.

Comment: Of course, Real Women and Real Men don't use Excel in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, the words became closer this way.

Comment: You care what's actually in the file and whether it's compatible with the import settings you use in Excel, not how it looks. If your Excel wants a comma instead of a tab, change to `tr -s ' ' ','`